# Is there a way to awaken an iOS app upon receiving a push notification even when it is killed

Tags: ios, push-notification, background-process

I need a way to receive a silent push notification, and then display a local one (so I can process data before displaying to user)
Is there a way to do this?
`didReceiveNotification` is only called when in the foreground.
I believe the app is launched when in background upon receiving push. However, there does not seem to be a solution for when the app is killed.

EDIT
I am aware of PushKit but my app is not a VOIP app, it is an IM app.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `UIApplicationDelegate` method [`didReceiveRemoteNotification:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) to receive a 'silent' push when your app is in the foreground or background, but If your app is killed (force-quit from the switcher) then there is no way to receive the notification in your app.  The notification payload (if any) will still be displayed to the user, giving them the opportunity to launch your app from the notification.

The documentation for this delegate method states:

> In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications background mode,
>   the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state)
>   and puts it in the background state when a remote notification
>   arrives. However, the system does not automatically launch your app if
>   the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch
>   your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch
>   your app automatically again

Comment: I am not agree with your statement : _"but If your app is killed (force-quit from the switcher) then there is no way to receive the notification."._ If App is killed, still we will be able to get notification. Correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: It isn't my statement as such. It is Apple's - see the quoted text. Of course the notification will be delivered to the device, but not to the app delegate method.

Comment: @Paulw11 is saying correct when app is killed , notification is received but delegate won't be call. Its normal push notification. And if our app is in background state then  
application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:
method will call